# Ajax запрос с интервалом

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

Проблема в следующем надо AJAX запросом создать документ, потом открыть документ по id который был присвоен в первом запросе.

Но дело в том что запрос происходит слишком быстро и данные не успевают сохраниться и вывод файла соответственно не получается сделать, пробывал setTimeout и setInterval, но тогда при втором запросе не находит id который был присвоен в первом.

Как сделать небольшой интервал между первым и вторым запросом и что бы id оставалось во втором запросе ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('a.save').click(function call() {

    var text = $("#text").val();

    $.ajax({        //Тут присваиваем id
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  async:false,
  url: 'http://site.ru/document/?text='+text,
  success: function (jsondata) {
        var id = jsondata.id;
         returnValue(id);
    },
    error: $('.results').html('ошибка'),    
        }); 


function returnValue(id){ //Тут выводим по id
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'http://site.ru/document/'+id, 
  success: function(jsondata){
    var stdout = jsondata.stdout
    console.log(stdout);
            },
    error: $('.results2').html('ошибка'),
    })
}
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Было бы логичнее сделать задержку на сервере и возвращать ответ только после записи в файл.

На клиенте стОит воспользоваться промисами. Например сделать так:

```
$('a.save').click(function call() {
    var text = $("#text").val();

    $.ajax({ //Тут присваиваем id
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://site.ru/document/?text=' + text
    }).then(function(jsondata) {
        // тут создаем задержку в 500мс
        var defer = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function() {
            defer.resolve(jsondata);
        }, 500);
        return defer.promise();
    }, function() {
        // показываем 'ошибка' если неудачно выполнен первый запрос
        $('.results').html('ошибка');
    }).then(function(jsondata) {
        // выполняется второй запрос
        id = jsondata.id;
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://site.ru/document/' + id
        })
    }).then(function(jsondata) {
        // выполняется после удачного второго запроса
        var stdout = jsondata.stdout;
        console.log(stdout);
    }, function() {
        // показываем 'ошибка' если неудачно выполнен второй запрос
        $('.results').html('ошибка');
    });
});
```

И, кстати, вместо

```
error: $('.results').html('ошибка'),
```

cтоило написать хотя бы

```
error: function() {
    $('.results').html('ошибка');
},
```

иначе "ошибки" будут показаны в момент отправки запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Как ответили выше используйте промисы. Вот отличная статейка, советую уделить внимание "чейнингу" [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise#%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

```
    // сделать запрос
$.get('https://learn.javascript.ru/article/promise/user.json')
  // 1. Получить данные о пользователе в JSON и передать дальше
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    let user = JSON.parse(response);
    return user;
  })
  // 2. Получить информацию с github
  .then(user => {
    console.log(user);
    return httpGet(`https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}`);
  })
  // 3. Вывести аватар на 3 секунды (можно с анимацией)
  .then(githubUser => {
    console.log(githubUser);
    githubUser = JSON.parse(githubUser);

    let img = new Image();
    img.src = githubUser.avatar_url;
    img.className = "promise-avatar-example";
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    setTimeout(() => img.remove(), 3000); // (*)
  });
```

**При чейнинге, то есть последовательных вызовах .then…then…then, в каждый следующий then переходит результат от предыдущего.**